# How to open Open Hexagon on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, games

A link to the game: http://vittorioromeo.info/projects.html (It is the first game on the page).

There's a game I would like to install called Open Hexagon. The problem is that I don't know how to run it. I was able to extract the files, but I don't know how to open the game. I am also a Linux newbie, if that adds anything. Could someone who has installed this game please help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Which file did you download?

Comment: I downloaded the 2.0-RC1(Linux) one.

Comment: Actually, I installed the deb one and I was able to download it from the Gnome Software Center, but I don't know how to open it. Do you know how to open it?